# Can I use a variable for Python's URLLIB2 Password Manager object?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to understand Python's URLLIB2 module, specifically the [Password Manager object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm).

I can hard code the strings into the method like so:

```
password_manager.add_password(None, 'http://example.com', 'admin', 'password')
```

The above works just fine. However, if I want to iterate the uri and the password, it doesn't seem to work:

```
hosts = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
passwords = open(sys.argv[2]).readlines()

for ind_pass in passwords:
        for ind_hosts in hosts:
            url = 'http://' + ind_hosts
            password_manager.add_password(None, url, 'admin', ind_pass)
```

The exact same values inserted into the sys.argv indexes fails when called as a variable, but not when hard coded. Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong here?

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip the lines read from the file. It will have the newline character at the end.

```
password_manager.add_password(None, url, 'admin', ind_pass.strip())
```